# RPM without staging area

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

At some point in the past I used to be able to make rpms with a very small spec file, like this:

```
Name: php-gd
Version: 1
Release: 1
Summary: gd extension for PHP 5.3
Group: PHP
License: TM

%description
gd extension module for PHP 5.3.3

%files
/etc/php.d/gd.ini
/usr/local/lib/php/20090626/gd.so
```

This grabbed the two files from the filesystem and stuffed them into an rpm. It looks like things have changed so I have to use a staging area, which means that I have to make sure all the paths exist in the staging area, copy the files, etc. Sometimes I just want to jam one or two files in an rpm. Is there no way to avoid the staging area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try overriding %buildroot or %_topdir macros with "/". Which one will work depends on your rpmbuild version.